# grounding wire from ceiling with no place to attach to the fixture?

Tags: wire

I was took down my parents 45 year old kitchen light fixture to tighten a screw and when i went to put it back up i noticed that there was a grounding wire coming down from the ceiling but no place to attach it to on the fixture. was it safe to just leave touching the inside of the wire box?

Answer (score 2):

Preferred solution in that case is to attach the safety-ground wire to the box with a screw (if the box is metal), or wrap it around one of the fixture's mounting screws. As long as it makes a circuit to the box and the body of the fixture, it's doing it's job. (Of course if the fixture is non-conductive, it doesn't need grounding.)